# Importing a C# class into PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

I am experimenting with C# and PowerShell. It's quite straightforward to create a C# class within a PowerShell file, instantiate it, and use it, as demonstrated in the code below:

```
$code = @"
using System;
public abstract class Transporter : IDisposable
{
    public abstract void Transport(Order order);

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Suppress finalization.
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}

public class Order {
    public int Distance { get; set; }
    public bool Urgent { get; set; }
}

public class SeawayTransporter : Transporter
{
    public override void Transport(Order order)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The order transported by SeawayTransporter");
    }
}

public class AirwayTransporter : Transporter
{
    public override void Transport(Order order)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The order transported by AirwayTransporter");
    }
}

public class HighwayTransporter : Transporter
{
    public override void Transport(Order order)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The order transported by HighwayTransporter");
    }
}

"@
# use it!
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp 
$order = [Order]::new()
$order.Distance = 200
$order.Urgent=$false
$highway = [HighwayTransporter]::new()
$highway.Transport($order)
```

Now, I want to export the class definitions to a separate file, similar to a PowerShell module. However, I encounter a challenge because I am using an abstract class definition unfamiliar to PowerShell. Attempting to place class definitions inside a function and save it as a module (e.g., myCSharpModule.psm1), and then importing the module, does not seem to work. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: `Add-Type` has an `-OutputAssembly` parameter... Unclear what you mean by "Attempting to place class definitions inside a function and save it as a module (e.g., myCSharpModule.psm1), and then importing the module, does not seem to work." Are you looking to create a binary cmdlet ?

Comment: I just simply want to export the C# classes definition into a seperate file and not have it together with the implementaion. That's the PowerShell module for. I'm not creating a binary cmdlet (the code would be different..). And since the @code".." is not a function I can't put it into a PowerShell module and make it visible (import-module XXX) for the implementation. Hopefully it's clear now.

Comment: `Add-Type` also knows how to compile C# from a path. You can place your code in a `.cs` file then in the `psm1` you can `Add-Type` it.

Comment: thank you, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: One option is to save your C# code in a *.cs file and use ```Get-Content -Raw```  to read it into a string variable in your powershell module and then pass that to ```Add-Type``` to compile it on the fly. The advantage is you can open the *.cs file in VSCode and get syntax highlighting and colourising which makes it much easier to maintain - I've gone even further myself in the past and created a dummy *.csproj / *.sln and developed the C# code in Visual Studio with a unit test project to verify the code in CI, but just ```Get-Content``` \ ```Add-Type``` the *.cs files at runtime...

Comment: Good point, @mclayton; note that you don't need `Get-Content` - `Add-Type LiteralPath some.cs` works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to put your class definitions in a script-module file, `.psm1` (for on-demand import with [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module)), *as long as you also include the [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type) call*.

Here's a minimal example:

```bash
# Create a sample script module that compiles a minimal class definition.
@'
Add-Type '
public class Foo { public int Bar() { return 42; } }
'
'@ > sample.psm1

# Import the sample module.
Import-Module -Force ./sample.psm1

# Make use of the class
[Foo]::new().Bar() # -> 42
```

Note:

- You don't strictly need a [*module*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules) in  your case:

  - a regular `.ps1` script file that you can invoke directly will do.
  - You can even **save your C# code stand-alone as a regular `.cs` file and compile and load it on demand with `Add-Type -LiteralPath`**:

    - As [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton) points out, this gives you the benefit of C# syntax highlighting in your editor.
    - It is benign to make such a call repeatedly in a session - you only incur the compilation performance penalty in the *first* call.
    - Conversely, however, you'll need to start a *new session* if the content of the file has changed and you want to load the new code, for the reasons explained next.
- The usual limitations apply with respect to .NET assemblies having been loaded into a session (irrespective of wether loaded from an assembly *file* (`.dll`) or from a *dynamically crated* one, as in the case at hand):

  - The public types exposed by .NET assemblies are visible *session-globally*, in all scopes.
  - Such types cannot be *removed* from the session once loaded, because .NET assemblies cannot be unloaded.
  - To load a *modified* version of your C#-based class definitions, you'll therefore need to start a new session.